# Visual Studio 2012 crashes when code file is mapped to Layer Diagram of modeling project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash, mapping, layer, modeling

I have a web application that consists of both ASP Class and ASP.NET pages.  This web application is under TFS source control
I created another modeling project that is currently **NOT** under source control.
In the modeling project, I created a Layer Diagram.
Then I added the web application as a project to this solution.
I then opened Architecture Explorer and used solution view to view the web application files.
I filter by .aspx and attempted to drag  .aspx(s) to one of the layers on the diagram.
At first it looks like it works, a counter displays showing the count of items.

But then Visual Studio Crashes with the following error.
(Note: I have even tried a single file and get the same results.) Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Log Name:      Application

Source:        .NET Runtime

Date:          4/2/2013 8:07:31 AM

Event ID:      1026

Task Category: None
Level:         Error

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A
Description:
Application: devenv.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Comment: Are you running VS 2012 Update 1?  This fixed many bugs in the RTM version of VS 2012.

Comment: Yes I am running Visual Stuio Ultimate 2012 Update 1

Comment: see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e49850f-c0fb-4fab-9cfe-280cfcd42299/vs-bug-shown-as-fixed-in-ms-connect-but-how-can-i-fix-mine and